# Javascript Document Write X and Y

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have a question?
How do I output the value from input `x1`  and value from input `y1` with `document.write` in Javascript using `X` and `Y` as variables?

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {

var x1 = document.test.x1.value;
var y1 = document.test.y1.value;

var x = parseInt(x1)*parseInt(y1)

document.getElementById("x").value = x;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<form name="test">
inpout<br><br>
  <input type="number" name="x1" id="x1" style="width:70px"> X * 
  <input type="number" name="y1" id="y1" style="width:70px"> Y

<br><br>
    <input type="button" name="Solve" value="Solve" onclick="myFunction()" ><br>
<br><br>
OutPut =<output type="number" name="x" id="x" style="width:100px"></output> <br><br>

Documen.write X = .... Y =...
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: We don't do homework..

Comment: ehhehe.. ok im.. dlet my homework. and cange t questn..

Comment: We still know that it is your homework. Could you write normally and don't using shorts as: sm, wn... And where is the question?

Comment: hem...ok try again

Comment: I would start with something like http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/beginner/

Comment: You should buy a new keyboard -- it looks like the one you're using now is broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this help you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<form name="test">
input<br><br>
  <input type="number" name="x1" id="x1" style="width:70px"> X * 
  <input type="number" name="y1" id="y1" style="width:70px"> Y

<br><br>
    <input type="button" name="Solve" value="Solve" onclick="myFunction()" ><br>
<br><br>
OutPut =<output type="number" name="x" id="x" style="width:100px"></output> <br><br>
    <p id="info"></p>
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
        var x1 = document.forms['test']["x1"].value;
        var y1 = document.forms['test']["y1"].value;
        var x = x1 * y1;
        document.getElementById("x").value = x;
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "X : " + x1 + " Y : " + y1;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```